# MAUI AppShell Cannot Bind to FlyoutItemIsVisible

Tags: maui

I need to dynamically show/hide shell content in the menu system.
There is a bindable property called "FlyoutItemIsVisible" inherited from BaseShellItem.

[Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.flyoutitem?view=net-maui-7.0)

Binding to it results in this error:
Error   XFC0009 No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "FlyoutItemIsVisible", or mismatching type between value and property.  It should be noted this property can be set to "True" or "False".

[VS2022 Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQKnx.png)

My binding context is set properly because I am setting the text value of the Shell Item from the same View Model.

The Shell content should bind and show/hide based on the value of the item it is bound to.  I am not sure what is wrong, why it won't work.

I have tried it in VS2022 with dot net 7 and VS2022 Pre with the latest dot net 8 RC.

View

```
<Shell
    x:Class="AppShell.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AppShell"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Flyout"
    Title="AppShell">

    <ShellContent
        Title="{Binding HomeText}"
        FlyoutItemIsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage" />

</Shell>
```

Code Behind

```
public AppShell(AppShellViewModel vm)
{
    BindingContext = vm;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

ViewModel

```
namespace AppShell
{
    public partial class AppShellViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public AppShellViewModel()
        {
            HomeText = "Home";
            IsVisible = true;
        }

        [ObservableProperty]
        bool isVisible;

        [ObservableProperty]
        string homeText;
    }
}
```

A small demo of the project can be found here:  [https://github.com/cmhofmeister/mauiappshell](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: I don't see where the docs state that the property is bindable

Comment: At the AppShell, a lot of things doesn't appear to react to property changes. Even the `HomeText` property, if you were to change it, it does not update accordingly. Similar with the Flyouts, if you were to property bind the Title, the Icon and so forth, the AppShell also doesn't appear to react to changes to any of those. The only thing that seems to stick is the initial values that they were set to during construction. However, there is absolutely no problem to assigning the view model to the MainPage itself, so, visibility, title, etc can update on your MainPage and it will be reflected.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is related with [FlyoutItemIsVisible should accept a "BindableObject" (i.e. it should be data bound)](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10960).

> Error XFC0009 No property, BindableProperty, or event found for
> "FlyoutItemIsVisible", or mismatching type between value and property.

The above error indicates that [FlyoutItemIsVisible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.baseshellitem.flyoutitemisvisible?view=net-maui-7.0) is not a bindable property so you can't use data binding.

However, you can still enclose the `ShellContent` with Tab inside the `FlyoutItem` and then use `IsVisible` to show/hide based on the value of the item it is bound to like below:

```
<Shell
    x:Class="AppShell.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AppShell"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Flyout"
    Title="AppShell">

    <FlyoutItem   Title="{Binding HomeText}" IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}"> 
        <Tab>
            <ShellContent
              ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
              Route="MainPage" />
        </Tab>
    </FlyoutItem>

</Shell>
```